# Cannot use map for getting useState data

Tags: reactjs, state

I'm trying to print my state but I cannot access it with a map because it's not an Array

I create like this :

```
const [state, setState] = React.useState({
    checkedA: "",
    checkedB: ""})
```

When I console.log my state it render :

```
state: {checkedA: "test", checkedB: "test2"}
```

I try to create an Array and split(',') but same error

"state.split is not a function"

Any idea how to access to it?

Comment: What are you trying to do with that object? .split() and .map() are array methods. Are you trying to display checkedA and checkedB on screen?

Comment: @ChristopherNgo I try to check if there is something inside checkeA, B ... to push them inside a string

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Object.values()` to take the values of your object and put them in an array. Then use `.join()` to turn them into a single string.

```
state: {checkedA: "test", checkedB: "test2"}

Object.values(state).join("") <-- returns "testtest2"
```